# Python3: eval() with custom dict not evaluating numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, eval, built-in

I'm working on an application which allows a user to define a math function by entering a string (like you see on wolfram alpha) and plotting the function over some pre-defined range. I use the eval() function to interpret the string and fill a list of y-values (list of x-values already defined). I only allow eval() access to a few common numpy math functions and the variable name 'x'.

This class allows me to make an object for each string entered by the user and create two lists, x and y, for plotting with matplotlib. You can run this MWE and see that it handles functions of x fine (e.g., sin(x), ln(x), 3*x, etc.) and throws exceptions for non-math functions like 'foo' as desired. However, giving it a number like '3' or '4.00' causes the eval() to write nothing into the self.y list. You can print the shape of self.y at various points in the code and you see that as soon as eval() runs (when the entered string is a number) the shape of self.y becomes ().

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class functionType():

    def __init__(self, funcStr, xlo=0.0, xhi=10.0, res=100):

        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.xlo = xlo
        self.xhi = xhi
        self.res = res
        self.funcStr = funcStr
        self.x = np.linspace(self.xlo, self.xhi, self.res)
        self.safe_dict = {'np':np,
                          'sin':np.sin,
                          'cos':np.cos,
                          'tan':np.tan,
                          'arcsin':np.arcsin,
                          'arccos':np.arccos,
                          'arctan':np.arctan,
                          'sinh':np.sinh,
                          'cosh':np.cosh,
                          'tanh':np.tanh,
                          'arcsinh':np.arcsinh,
                          'arccosh':np.arccosh,
                          'arctanh':np.arctanh,
                          'ln':np.log,
                          'log10':np.log10,
                          'log2':np.log2,
                          'exp':np.exp,
                          'sqrt':np.sqrt,
                          'abs':np.fabs,
                          'x':self.x}

        try:
            self.y = eval(self.funcStr,{__builtins__:None},self.safe_dict)
        except Exception:
            raise Exception

    def _reMakeData(self):

        self.x = np.linspace(self.xlo, self.xhi, self.res)
        self.safe_dict['x'] = self.x
        self.y = eval(self.funcStr,{__builtins__:None},self.safe_dict)

    def setXLow(self, value):
        self.xlo = value
        self._reMakeData()

    def setXHigh(self, value):
        self.xhi = value
        self._reMakeData()

    def setRes(self, value):
        self.res = value
        self._reMakeData()

    def getXLow(self):
        return self.xlo

    def getXHigh(self):
        return self.xhi

    def getRes(self):
        return self.res

    def getData(self):
        return self.x, self.y



func = input("gimme a function:  ")
try:
    plot1 = functionType(func)
    x, y = plot1.getData()
    plt.plot(x,y,marker='',color='red')
    plt.show()
except Exception as e:
    print("no good:  ",e)
```

Does anyone see the problem here? I'd like to be able to handle the user wanting to plot a constant function. To be clear, when I give it a constant like 4.0 I want it to write a list into self.y (it's actually a 1D numpy array but we needn't be pedantic) the same length as self.x filled with 4.0's.

This is not for a web or server application, I'm perfectly aware of the risks inherent to eval() so please no finger waggling about using it :)

Comment: Could you give a minimal example to describe the intended functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that plot needs the list of y values to be the same length as the list of x values.  If the expression you input involves `x`, this works fine, because `x` is a numpy array, so doing mathematical operations on it will produce an array of the same length.  But if you just input a number `y` gets set to a single number, not an array at all.

One possibility would be to check after setting `y` whether it is a numpy array, and if not, assume it is a single number and repeat it the appropriate number of times:

```
    if not isinstance(self.y, np.ndarray):
        self.y = np.repeat(self.y, len(self.x))
```

Your code has several other errors and strange things.  In your dict that you pass to `eval`, you want to use `{'__builtins__': None}`, with quotes around `__builtins__`.  Also, your use of try/except is pretty pointless.  Doing `except Exception` followed immediately by `raise Exception` accomplishes nothing, and hides the information about what kind of exception was raised.  Just remove the try/except; if an exception is raised, it will propagate up and you will see what kind of exception it is.  Likewise your try/except at the end isn't useful; all it does is print a message that is less informative than the message that would have been printed if you hadn't caught the exception.

Comment: I added your suggestion of checking the class type of self.y and that handled the problem well. Thanks for your concise and helpful answer.  I also corrected the other problems you saw and will catch exceptions outside of the class. Thank you kindly, neighbour.